# Get the 3 Strings behind each other from the line by regex expresion

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line

> Nach unserer Information handelt es sich bei dieser Bedarfsanforderung
>   um einen Folgeabruf für ein anderes Konsortium. Diese Information
>   erfolgt ohne Gewähr.

and I am trying to get the 3 strings `ein anderes Konsortium` from the line but currently the `kgString` is empty. It is important for me to keep the `KEYWORD, MULTIMATCHPATTERN, INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR` structure. How can I get the `ein anderes Konsortium` String from the line by regex?

```
public class KlassifizierungsgruppenParser  implements BedarfsanforderungParser  {

    private static final String KEYWORD = ".*Nach unserer Information handelt es sich bei dieser Bedarfsanforderung um einen Folgeabruf ";
    private static final String MULTIMATCHPATTERN = "[\\s\\*\\t]*";
    private static final String INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR = "(ein\\s.*anderes.*Konsortium)"; 

    private static final Pattern KGPATTERN = Pattern.compile("^" + KEYWORD + MULTIMATCHPATTERN + INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR + "$", Pattern.MULTILINE);   

    @Override
    public void parse(String volltext, Abruf abruf) {

        fillKG(volltext, abruf);
    }

    private void fillKG(String volltext, Abruf abruf) {

        System.out.println("volltext: "  + volltext);

        String kgString = getKg(volltext);
            System.out.println("kgString: " + kgString);

    }

    private String getKg(String volltext) { 
        Matcher matcher = KGPATTERN.matcher(volltext);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Why do you have `\\s` after `ein` in `INFORMATIONSEXTRAKTOR`?

Comment: because I have `ein` and `einen` in the line. But I think it does not matter now because I Extended the KEYWORD by `um einen Folgeabruf`... I have removed it but it is still emtpy

Comment: As a side note: you may want to use english names for your classes and variables by convention. This makes it easier for people reading your code later (or on the web in this case) :)

Comment: `\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+(?=\\.)` takes the 3 words before the first `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern compiles to `"^.*Nach unserer Information handelt es sich bei dieser Bedarfsanforderung um einen Folgeabruf [\\s\\*\\t]*(ein\\s.*anderes.*Konsortium)$"` and there are two places that it does not match the input:

1. `[\\s\\*\\t]*` does not match `für` - either use `.*` instead, or add `für` to KEYWORD.
2. `$` does not match `". Diese Information erfolgt ohne Gewähr."` You may want to remove it.

> You may also want to practice your regular expression (e.g. https://regex101.com/, https://regexr.com/, https://www.regextester.com/ etc.) to better learn how it works.